# Kibana Dashboard - Filter bar is not visible

Tags: google-chrome, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a dashboard where filter bar is not visible Hence not able to remove or update filter. Kibana version used is 4.5.0 and browser used is chrome (version 48.0.2564.97)

Comment: Filter bar was not visible even after applying the filter. Issue identified and resolved. look like incorrect filter applied and saved. Edited the dashboard json (Settings>Objects>select dashboard>edit>clean up filter json). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The filter bar only shows up if there's a filter defined.  For example no filter in use:
[image: no filter]

But as soon as you add a filter it will show up:
[image]

Comment: Filter bar was not visible even after applying the filter. Issue identified and resolved. Find the solution in the comment given in question above. Thanks